# how to shut down a networked linux pc?

Tags: linux

For an example my internet protocol is `192.168.1.2` and `username`: `martin` ,`password`: `martin123` 
an other PC in my private network internet protocol: `192.168.1.3` and `username`: `doll`, `password`: `doll123`

What is the command to shutdown the doll PC through `martin` `terminal`?
Please help...

Comment: You cannot shutdown directly via network. You have to have 1. a shell on the target system and 2. administrative rights. So the easiest is to login using ssh and then to execute `shutdown -h now` as `root` user.

Comment: You might be able to use the WOL (Wake-on-LAN) feature of the Ethernet card to do that, e.g. [wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN).

Answer (score 4):

```
> ssh doll@192.168.1.3 -P doll123 -c 'sudo shutdown -h now'
```

Assuming that doll@192.168.1.3 is allowed sudo access to the shutdown command without a password.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `ssh` into the machine, and run the `shutdown` command.

```
ssh martin@192.168.1.2
```

Enter your password.

```
shutdown -h now
```

You may need to `root` permission to run this command. In that case you will need to either `ssh` in as `root` using `ssh root@your.ip` and use the root password, or run

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

And you should be prompted to enter in a password, enter in `root`'s password and then this will shutdown the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good. If you want to be fancy about it, you **could** write a program that runs upon startup, but stays in the background.

It would simply open a TCP/IP port and wait for a command. When it sees a valid command, it takes action. Of course, your command would be the signal to shutdown.

Again, this is just so you know you can do something like that. The other answers are **far** easier to do.